# Table View Scrolling cause problems when I use dynamic data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, uitableview

When I use static data there is no problem but I use dynamic data with Web services there is problem (table view scrolling cause crash program) why? If I comment these lines add static data it works;

```
//tempCs is NSDictionary
tempDc = [arrHaberler objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [tempDc valueForKey:@"short_header"];

NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[tempDc valueForKey:@"iphone_src"]]];
UIImage *myImage = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData] autorelease];
cell.imageView.image = myImage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't release the imgData. You'd want to do that after creating the UIImage.

Other than that, from your description, maybe the numbersOfRowsInSection method has an error?

---

EDIT (after discussion):

(crash due to unrecognized selector (ie method from NSArray) sent to instance of NSString)

There are many ways you can come to this state, including accessing some memory that was released and reused (ie missing a retain), or overwriting an array with a string due to some parsing yielding a wrong result.

Comment: it has 7 rows bur I don't think so it's related that because when I use static data there is no problem... I comment all line except tempDc = [arrHaberler objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; and it still crash... so that's not about images or dynamic datas... its all about assign data to NSDictionary...

Comment: What kind of crash are you having? EXC_BAD_ACCESS? Uncaught exception?

Comment: Crash Error: [NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d4d3d0

I think after scrolling arrHaberler (NSArray) no more data include... after scrolling it is empty but I dont know why because I loaded data to NSArray in viewDidLoad() method...

Comment: Well, here's your error. You think you have an array, when the data your var (arrHaberler) points to is actually an NSString.

Comment: hımm dear jv42, if it in not an array how can it load data on viewDidLoad() ? Because it is the same code... In viewDidLoad it works because I watch  it with NSLog() on console I saw the data, also it came to tablecell.. After scrolling it crash.. after scrolling it transform to NSString?

Comment: There are many ways you can come to this state, including accessing some memory that was released and reused (ie missing a retain), or overwriting an array with a string due to some parsing yielding a wrong result.

Comment: You are so right but I am totally sure about not overwriting NSArray or memory release/retain problem because I create an sample plist and try with that it worked. I don't understand it work with .plist file which I created but it didn't work with as i ask with using webservices data. There is no problem taking a data from web services with JSon format and parse it to array because I can see that on viewDidLoad() method... I am really confuse..

Comment: Well, without more code, I don't think I can help further, sorry.

Comment: I forget to use "retain" it solve the problem.

arrHaberler = [[baglanti baglanJSonDondur] retain];

Thank you for all helping jv42 :)

Answer (score 1):

I try something with made an comment another lines and problem is on this line:

tempDc = [arrHaberler objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

I change "indexPath.row" to "0" still cause crash... Problem about when is assign data to NSDictionary

Answer (score 0):

There is no null-checking (setting `NSData *imgData` and setting `UIImage *myImage`) and there in a synchronous call to server. fmpov, problem is out there.

Comment: I try something with made an comment another lines and problem is on this line: 

   tempDc = [arrHaberler objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

I change "indexPath.row" to "0" still cause crash... Problem about when is assign data to NSDictionary...

Comment: Null checking is rarely the answer with ObjectiveC, where calling methods on null is valid. It's the answer when trying to store null in a container (NSArray, NSDictionary, etc).

Comment: that is exactly what I've meant

Answer (score 0):

@VNevzatR i am just asking you that Are you are calling plenty no of images from somewhere....because this is no the problem you `UITableView` as you said working fine in static data,the problem is some where else, so if you are calling plenty of images at a time....Try doing this way...release that pool.

```
-(void) parseImages
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    //Fetch your images here

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(Done) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    [pool release];
}

-(void) Done {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Hope it will resolve your problem...Good Luck

Comment: Thank you for answer john but as I said below, assign data to NSDictioanry cause problem... that is not related with images, I take images from some server and these are exactly exist. Thank you for help..

Comment: please try to check by applying breakpoints at several places through debugger...

Comment: I listen your help, I used breakpoints and I found the error after scrolling array will come empty... Bu I haven't solve yet...